# creating (multi) bootable ISO with partition for data

Tags: linux, boot, usb

I know this question was asked A LOT. I'm asking it again, because most of the answer does not work.

So I have this big usb, and I'd like to have at least 1 bootable live distro on it, and data on separate partition. I really don't know how to do it. I created 2 primary partitions accordingly. `fedora media writer` does not support that, whole drive needs to be sacrificed. Same for "frequently" used example of `dd`. `Unetbootin` does support that, you can write to specific partition, but arch specifically warns againts using this tool, and on top of that, booting from such create usb does not work.

Even better goal would be to have multiple bootable live distros (it's a big usb), but that goal is even more distant. There is tool named `multibootusb`, which seems to freeze a lot, but once you have understanding how it works, it can be used to create multi distro bootable usb. The drawback is, that it does not reliably work — for example Manjaro get corrupted in process and boot menu does not work correctly, but even if you get past that, the installer works weird (like missing locale entries, missing timezones in installer menus — maybe more, I left here)

Is there another way how to achieve any of these? ~ at least 1 live distro + data partition, or multiple distros + data. All in reliable, dependable way, no half-destroyed/half-working distros?

Comment: The Ubuntu startup disk creator has that as a standard option.

Comment: Does it, actually? a) it does not allow you to write fedora iso to begin with b) it does not allow you to specify partition. So to wrap it up, it does not seem to do anything this question asked about.

Comment: @MartinMucha Have you considered [Easy2Boot](https://www.easy2boot.com/download/)?

Comment: @MartinMucha what gives you the impression, you can't write a Fedora image with it? And what gives you the impression, it can't create a data partition?

Comment: @JW0914 I'm not close to the windows box, and I'm having hard times even to understand the claimed functionality of Easy2Boot. Pages and pages of text, no specific claims what it can do made. Which of mine scenario does it cover? If it does, then THANKS! I will try that, but please help me with confirmation, that it actually can write linux images reliably and can support data partition

Comment: @EugenRieck maybe I just don't understand this tool. In ubuntu 18.04 it looks like this:
https://pasteboard.co/Ja0ehnc.png  So it seems, that I have only 2 options on beginning: quit program, or select image. If I select fedora image, which is completely valid and can be written via other methods to usb, I'm presented with the same options: either select new iso, or quit. So regular grammar is: "A -> A | quit" I totally don't see any option to select partition.

Comment: @MartinMucha The data provided on Easy2Boot's webpage aren't _"claims"_, it's explaining how it works & how to configure it. What you're requesting in your question is the purpose of it - Please take the time to read it, starting with the [Inntroduction](https://www.easy2boot.com/introduction/#intro) _(under More Info > Start & Intro link in the previous comment's Download link)_. Also, see [Use Linux to Make an E2B Drive](https://www.easy2boot.com/make-an-easy2boot-usb-drive/make-using-linux/). Easy2Boot was created by the same developer that created [RMPrepUSB](https://www.rmprepusb.com/)

Comment: @JW0914 what I meant by that is, that lot of programs makes claims which then aren't met. Here I even cannot see what is claimed or what this program does. I'm asking here to get recommendation what works for my usecase. And since you didn't said it, and it's not written anywhere on page, I'm just asking — can it do multiboot usb or single os boot parttion and data partition? Yes/no. I cannot read 50 pages of every product to evaluate if it's worthy to read it. It's not about arrogancy/laziness. I already threw several hours away evaluating 5 tools which lied in their description.

Comment: @MartinMucha I've provided links in my last comment - I suggested the software because it does what you're looking for and it's not my job to do your legwork for you... you came to Superuser for help, I've provided a method to do what you need and you can take the suggestion or reject it, but I would hope a sugestion by a StackExchange user would carry weight that what was being suggested works for what you're looking for.  E2B allows booting multiple OSes, is relatively easy to use, highly customizable, and is one of the most versatile tools for USB drives I've come across.

Comment: @JW0914 GREAT! Thank you, this is the only thing I was asking about. Sure, now I need to read it, which I will. I was asking just to be sure if it really does what I'm looking for, as I (still) cannot see it anywhere written on that page. Thanks for your recommendation!

Comment: @MartinMucha Unfortunately, the developer over-uses formatting on their site, so it doesn't make for the best laid out information, The [RMPrepUSB](https://www.rmprepusb.com/) page gives a fairly concise outline of what it does (2nd paragraph down), as it's from where many come across Easy2Boot [E2B] from.

Comment: @JW0914 yes, it's little bit harder to read + I have some mental disorder or something and I cannot read modern-looking pages with chaotic layout. I'm not complaining, it's just my limit. Add too much work + not enough time factors on top of it, and one can easily look online like an asshole. So sorry about that, and thanks again for your recommendation. I'll give it a shot in the evening.

Comment: @EugenRieck if there is however a method, in which this can be achieved in ubuntu, please explain. I can use Windows products, but if it's possible in linux, I'd definitely favor that method.